# Why isn't my javascript code scrolling on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code works great when I test it, but when it's embedded into the website it no longer scrolls down to reveal the images below. It's static. I've tried adding overflow:visible but to no avail. Any idea on what I need to change? Here is a link to the website page where it's not working. https://den-of-dreamers-45.showitpreview.com/new-page-1

Thank you!

```js
var PHOTODATA = [{
    id: 1,
    category: 'cottagecore',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/U0ucmfm5T22dFNiq2ejzSw/118367/pexels-nadi-lindsay-4990969_1.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category: 'cottagecore',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/I1dybkKETdq4ijozGfDs3w/118367/pexels-anete-lusina-6354251.jpg'
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    category: 'cottagecore',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/MpOOhlgLSZ2b__8uTuKBJQ/118367/pexels-photo-10213893.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    category: 'academia',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/5xDz3V4KTi63UoOKKbAlYQ/118367/ashley-winkler-yzhnw0qiqo0-unsplash.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    category: 'academia',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/ybGpWcTnQmS-beO1R4LqqQ/118367/mel-poole-ppuz3fosru8-unsplash.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    category: 'academia',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/9td2KJYPQuypgOrKrM20SA/118367/pexels-roman-odintsov-8349176.jpg'
  },

  {
    id: 7,
    category: 'ethereal',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/RjY3KcUERsWnjlKbWmkepw/118367/screen_shot_2022-02-03_at_6_43_28_pm.png'
  },

  {
    id: 8,
    category: 'ethereal',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/cgx9GCzlRQSoAufxS9dw3w/118367/pexels-ron-lach-10536607.jpg'
  },
  {

    id: 9,
    category: 'ethereal',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/FZICN6rlRkiZ4hAkdxdc0Q/118367/pexels-tatiana-twinslol-5444997.jpg'
  },

  {
    id: 10,
    category: 'tropical',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/iaEUuhQiQkajqRkvzCuibw/118367/pexels-alan-cabello-1173217.jpg'
  },

  {
    id: 11,
    category: 'tropical',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/HpWQ15TsSFKlaQEWXtcBcQ/118367/pexels-michael-block-3225531_1.jpg'
  },

  {
    id: 12,
    category: 'tropical',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.showit.co/file/LXrsgIh6TA6iG0JSuAMlYw/118367/pexels-ryan-delfin-2270389.jpg'
  }
];

{ /*Create a component of the filter panel*/ }

var FilterPanel = React.createClass({
  displayName: "FilterPanel",

  render: function() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/ (
      React.createElement("a", {
        onClick: this.props.onClick
      }, this.props.category));


  }
});



{ /*Create a layout component for one photo*/ }

var Photo = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Photo",

  render: function() {
    return /*#__PURE__*/ (
      React.createElement("div", {
        className: "photo-container",
        "data-category": this.props.category
      }, /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement("img", {
        src: this.props.imageUrl
      })));

  }
});



{ /*Create a final collection of photos in photoGallery*/ }

var PhotoGallery = React.createClass({
  displayName: "PhotoGallery",

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      displayedCategories: PHOTODATA,
      active: false
    };

  },
  toggleActive: function() {
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active
    });

  },

  selectCategory: function(element) {
    console.log('element is: ' + element);
    var categoryName = element.toLowerCase();
    var displayedCategories = PHOTODATA.filter(function(el) {

      var searchValue = el.category.toLowerCase();
      return searchValue.indexOf(categoryName) !== -1;
    });

    this.setState({
      displayedCategories: displayedCategories
    });



  },
  resetFilter: function(element) {
    this.setState({
      displayedCategories: PHOTODATA
    });


  },



  render: function() {
    var buttonClass = this.state.active ? 'active' : '';
    var categoryToSelect = this.selectCategory;
    var getUniqueCategories = [];
    PHOTODATA.forEach(function(el) {
      if (getUniqueCategories.indexOf(el.category) === -1) getUniqueCategories.push(el.category);
    });

    return /*#__PURE__*/ (
      React.createElement("div", {
          className: "overlay-photogallery"
        }, /*#__PURE__*/
        React.createElement("div", {
            className: "filter-panel"
          },

          getUniqueCategories.map(function(el, i) {
            var boundClick = categoryToSelect.bind(null, el);
            return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(FilterPanel, {
              onClick: boundClick,
              category: el,
              key: i
            });
          }), /*#__PURE__*/


          React.createElement("a", {
            className: "resetBtn",
            onClick: this.resetFilter
          }, " Reset Filter ")), /*#__PURE__*/

        React.createElement("div", {
            className: "PhotoGallery"
          },


          this.state.displayedCategories.map(function(el) {
            return /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(Photo, {
              key: el.id,
              imageUrl: el.imageUrl,
              category: el.category
            });
          }))));

  }
});

ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement(PhotoGallery, null), document.getElementById('main'));
```

```css
.PhotoGallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.photo-container {
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  animation: fadeUP .5s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .photo-container img {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .photo-container img {
    max-width: 140px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeUP {
  from {
    top: -40px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .filter-panel {
    display: flex;
    padding: 25px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .filter-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .filter-panel a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    transition: .25s ease-in;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: cormorant;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  .filter-panel a {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 18px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 3px;
    transition: .25s ease-in;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: cormorant;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.filter-panel a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.filter-panel a.active {
  top: -8px;
}

.filter-panel a.resetBtn {
  background: #b37351;
}

.filter-panel a.resetBtn:hover {
  background: #b37351;
}
```

```html
<title>Image filter with React.js (get from jSON)</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>



<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: What's with the react versions? We can load these into the snippet `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Look in the network and console. You have a 404 on the stylesheet

Comment: You have an [external stylesheet](http://lib.showit.co/engine/1.5.4/showit.css) on your website that adds the rules `.sp{min-width:320px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden}` to your root container `<div id="si-sp" class="sp" style="">`, thus it is not scrollable due to `overflow-y:hidden` rule.

Comment: @n-- Thank you! Looks like the external stylesheet is `<link rel=“stylesheet” type=“text/css” href=“//lib.showit.co/engine/1.5.4/showit.css”>` If I adjust "hidden" to "visible" in the internal css.. do you think that would fix it?

Comment: @denofdreamers yes, you may add a ruleset `.sp { overflow-y: visible; }` in the `css/style.css` and it will work.

Comment: @n-- Ok thank you! I'm not super familiar with that but will do some research